# Django-How to deny access to a logged user directly to a specific URL

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-sessions

at my project we need some sort of system for allowing/denying some access to an URL.

The example, we want to make some kind of wizard.

The user inputs the first object at the the first screen (A screen), and then he press "Continue".
Now we get the data and redirect to a second screen (B screen), where we the user should enter a second object.
The wizard goes on...
The problem is that if we do so, the user can write the B url at the browser and access the B screen. The user has made the login, but even so, we don't want him to get there without passing through A screen.

We don't know how to achieve this or look for this in internet. We only know about user session for doing this.

Is there another way? Some help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's wrong with using the session?

Comment: Have you looked at [django's form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)?

Answer (score 1):

I think foreign key is the solution you are looking for make 'A' as the foreign-key of 'B' and in the url of the 'B' pass the id of 'A' as argument like this `url(r'^A/(?P<A_id>[0-9]+)` this way first user will input data in 'A' it will get stored in database then accesing your 'B' will be available through id of 'A'. Read more about foreign-key [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I'm working on a mathematics homework project. There are three types of users. Professors, students, and admins. The following snippet will deny user to access a url based on the users' type. After you modify it, you will have to add this method decorator to your request method that serve the http request.

```
def deny_a_thing(function):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
        try:
            test = User.objects.get(username=request.user)   # This will get the username
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise Http404                                    # return 404, if the user doesn't exist. You can change it to anything
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():              # If the user is not authenticated, return to the rootm. You can also change this.
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        try:
            if test.groups.filter()[0].name != "professors": # Add your test here. E.g: If user saved A, don't go B.
                raise Http404
        except IndexError:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

Add the following to your method

```
@deny_a_thing                   # This will deny the user from doing the thing you didn't want the user to do.
def some_page_request(request):
    return HttpResponse("OMG")
```

Check this [link](http://mrcoles.com/blog/3-decorator-examples-and-awesome-python/) for a simpler decorator